# How to loop over dictionary efficiently and should I use another data structure

Tags: python, dictionary, data-structures

I have one called dict1. Of course, the dicts are made up and the real dictionary is of larger size.

```
dict1 = {'USA_Mark': ['dog'],
         'USA_Haechan': ['lion', 'jaguar'],
         'USA_Mina': ['apples', 'pears', 'watermelons'],
         'UK_Mark': ['dog'],
         'UK_Haechan': ['lion', 'jaguar', 'tiger'],
         'UK_Mina': ['apples', 'pears', 'watermelons']}
```

I have another dict2 which contains something like this:

```
dict2 = {'USA_cats':['lion', 'jaguar'], 'USA_fruits':['apples, 'pears', 'watermelons'],
         'UK_cats':['lion', 'jaguar', 'tiger'], 'UK_fruits':['apples, 'pears', 'watermelons']}
```

What I want in the end is to map `dict2's` keys to `dict1's` values.

I did it in a hard-coded way. What I did was:

```
for key, value in dict1.items():
    if 'Haechan' in key and len(value ) > 1:
        dict1[key] = dict2['{} cats'.format(key[:2])]
    elif 'Mina' in key and len(value) > 1:
        dict1[key] = dict2['{} fruits'.format(key[:2])]
```

Expected results:

```
dict1 = {'USA_Mark': ['dog'],
         'USA_Haechan': ['USA_cats'],
         'USA_Mina': ['USA_fruits'],
         'UK_Mark': ['dog'],
         'UK_Haechan': ['UK_cats'],
         'UK_Mina': ['UK_fruits']}
```

This is not efficient, and I know it, may I know a better way to do this, I seem to use looping in dictionary a lot, and I heard from my friends that if you do this consistently, you might need to consider a better data structure...

Comment: Where does your code get anything from `dict2`?

Comment: @Barmar Sorry edited, but this is not gonna work properly since I am hardcoding `key[:2]`

Comment: `dict2['{} cats'.format(key[:2])]` is not `['USA_cats']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the key at the `_` character, then use a dictionary to map the second part of the key to the translated word.

```
mapping = {'Haechan': 'cats', 'Mina': 'fruits'}
for key, value in dict1.items():
    country, type = key.split('_')
    if type in mapping and len(value) > 1:
        dict1[key] = [f'{country}_{mapping[type]}']
```